# Changing product text from short product description to post details

Tags: wordpress

Hy i have a question, I am working at a ecommerce site and i would like to change the products text from the short product description to post details(post details is in the picture). Is there any plugin or what can i do to change this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: 
WooCommerce Jetpack - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-jetpack/

Hope it can help.